# How can I create sitemap nodes for ASP.Net MVC2 using MvcSiteMap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

I want to use MvcSiteMap to define a sitemap of my controllers and actions, to let me generate breadcrumbs and menus.

I have tried using the below decorators to add nodes programmatically, but unfortunately it will not make my tree like I want.

```
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Title = "Home"]
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Title = "Services", ParentKey = "Home")]
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Title = "Service detail", ParentKey = "Services")]
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Title = "Edit", ParentKey = "Service detail")]
```

How can I decorate my actions to make sure the child/parent relations are made how I want?

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // Home
    public ActionResult Index ()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

[HandleError]
public class ServiceController : Controller
{
    // Home > Services
    public ActionResult Index ()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Home > Services > Service detail
    public ActionResult Details (int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Home > Services > Service detail > Edit
    public ActionResult Edit (int id)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set the key as well:

```
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Key = "Home", Title = "Home"]
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Key = "Services", Title = "Services", ParentKey = "Home")]
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Key = "ServiceDetail", Title = "Service detail", ParentKey = "Services")]
[MvcSiteMapNodeAttribute(Title = "Edit", ParentKey = "ServiceDetail")]
```